# R function name seems to change randomly halfway through script execution

Tags: r, ubuntu, igraph

I'm having a problem where a function name seems to be changing halfway through the execution of a long R script... or rather, R seems to try to call a function which obviously does not exist, and which is not mentioned in my code. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: could not find function "get.shohortest.paths"
Execution halted
```

Obviously, you will think, this is a dumb typo and that what I surely meant to call was 'get.shortest.paths'. Well, yes, that is the function I meant to call and it is the one which I did call in my script. The strange thing is that the script successfully gets through dozens of calls to the correct function before it throws an error by seemingly making a random typo and trying to call a function which doesn't exist. 
Interestingly, there was another permutation of the problem at roughly the same point in my script, but using a different dataset, where the error was slightly different (I deleted the log, so I don't have it exactly), like

```
Error: could not find function "get.srtest.paths"
Execution halted
```

On smaller test datasets, the problem has not presented and execution has completed successfully.

My code is below. I have been trying to run this on a remote Ubuntu machine using Rbatch to run the script in the background, while dumping output in a text file.

```
nohup Rscript script_name.r > output.out 2>&1 &
```

My graph (variable 'g', an igraph graph object) has between 200k and 300k edges. Essentially I'm just trying to find edges which are not the shortest paths between their own nodes.

```
##############################
# FIND SHORTEST PATHS
##############################

#create a field for storing whether this edge is part of 
# a shortest path. Default to False
E(g)$in_shortest = F

# run the process separately for each connected component 
# if there are more than one
for(comp in unique(E(g)$component)){

    print(paste('finding shortest paths for component',comp))

    # find the vertices of this component
    component_vertices = V(g)[inc(E(g)[E(g)$component==comp])]

    direct_edges = c()

    # Find some random shortest paths within each component
    for(i in 1:25){
        paths = get.shortest.paths(
            g,
            from=sample(component_vertices,1),
            # from random node to a sample of nodes
            to=sample(
                component_vertices,
                round(length(component_vertices)*0.015),
                replace=F
            ),
            output='epath'
        )
        # mark the paths in the graph which are definitely shortest
        for(path in paths$epath){
            direct_edges = union( direct_edges, as.vector(path) )
        }
        # how much did this iteration add?
        print(paste( 'known direct', length(direct_edges)/length(E(g)),'on i',i ))
    }
    # store the data in the graph
    E(g)[direct_edges]$in_shortest = T
}


print('measuring directness directly')
# default directness is 1
E(g)$directness = 1

# now iterate over those edges which are not yet known to be the shortest possible
check = E(g)[ !E(g)$in_shortest ]

for( i in 1:length(check) ){
    # occassional output
    if(i%%30==0){ print( length(check) - i) }

    edge = check[[i]]
    # get the nodes at either end of the edge
    inc_nodes = V(g)[ inc(edge) ]
    result = get.shortest.paths(
        g,
        inc_nodes[[1]],
        inc_nodes[[2]],
        output='epath'
    )
    # check to see if the path is identical to the edge
    if( length(result$epath[[1]])!=1 ){
        # edge is NOT shortest. 
        # assign directness value
        shortest_path = sum(result$epath[[1]]$weight)
        ratio = shortest_path / edge$weight
        E(g)[ as.vector(edge) ]$directness = ratio

    }else if( edge == result$epath[[1]] ){
        E(g)[ as.vector(edge) ]$in_shortest = T

    }else{
        # edge is NOT shortest. 
        # assign directness value
        shortest_path = result$epath[[1]]$weight
        ratio = shortest_path / edge$weight
        E(g)[ as.vector(edge) ]$directness = ratio
    }
}
```